# Comparing datatable content and counting differences

Tags: c#, excel, loops, datatable

Every day, I receive a spreadsheet that has the following form:

| STATE | Probable | Confirmed | Total | Deaths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

There are no missing cells. The maximum number of rows is 60 (includes territories) and maybe 10 columns.

One of the tasks that I must do is compare the current spreadsheet with the previous day's spreadsheet.  There are more columns than this, but it should give you the idea.

The code that I have works fine--it tells me which STATE has a difference from the day before. But, some STATEs may have one difference, other STATEs may have a difference for each column except the first.

What I would like to have added is the count of columns that are different.

So, if only two states had differences--Alaska had 3 columns that were different and Texas had 1 column, the result that I would like to have is:

Alaska (3)
Texas (1)

Here is my working code without the counter:

Thanks for any help.

```
        DataTable dt1 = GetDataTable(xlPath);
        DataTable dt2 = GetDataTable(xlPathYest);

        
        var diffStates = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray.SequenceEqual(dt2.Rows[i].ItemArray))
            {
                diffStates.Add((string)dt1.Rows[i][0]);
            }
        }

        diffDT = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, diffStates.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));

        Console.WriteLine(diffDT);
```

Comment: where do you want to show this counter?

Comment: @shubham Ideally, I'd like to have it next to the STATE name, which is column 0.